# C++ / Class compilation and string attribute : "expected `)' before '=' token"

Tags: c++, string, class

I am trying to compile a class of mail sending using sockets

However, I have that error during the compilation :

> expected `)' before '=' token

At the line where I declare the constructor :

```
Mail(ipSMTP="serveurmail.com", port=25)
```

I'm suspecting that the issue is coming from the two string attributes declared before the Mail() constructor :

Here is the code of the mail.h file, containing the Mail class declaration :

```
#if defined (WIN32)
#include <winsock2.h>
typedef int socklen_t;
#elif defined (linux)
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define INVALID_SOCKET -1
#define SOCKET_ERROR -1
#define closesocket(s) close(s)
typedef int SOCKET;
typedef struct sockaddr_in SOCKADDR_IN;
typedef struct sockaddr SOCKADDR;
#endif

#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class Mail
{
  private :

  public :
         SOCKET sock;
         SOCKADDR_IN sin;
         char buffer[255];
         int erreur;
         int port;
         string message;
         string ipSMTP;

          Mail(ipSMTP="serveurmail.com", port=25)
          {
               #if defined (WIN32)
                WSADATA WSAData;
                erreur = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &WSAData);
                 #else
                    erreur = 0;
                 #endif

               message = "";

               /* Création de la socket */
                sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

                /* Configuration de la connexion */
                sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipSMTP.c_str());
                sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
                sin.sin_port = htons(port);
          }

          ~Mail()
          {
               /* On ferme la socket précédemment ouverte */
                    closesocket(sock);

                    #if defined (WIN32)
                        WSACleanup();
                    #endif
          }

          void envoi()
          {
               //Instructions d'envoi d'email par la socket via le SMTP
          } 
};
```

Comment: change you constructor  Mail(string ipSMTP="serveurmail.com",string port=25)

Comment: What made you even think this is proper C++ syntax? `Mail(string ipSMTP="serveurmail.com",string port=25)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the types of your constructor arguments, as well as assigning your members with the passed values.

```
Mail(ipSMTP="serveurmail.com", port=25)
{
```

should be written as

```
Mail (string const& ipSMTP = "serveurmail.com", int port =25)
  : port (port), ipSMTP (ipSMTP) // constructor initializer list
{
```

In the above we are assigning the member variables using a constructor initializer list, you can read more about it here:

[[10.6] Should my constructors use "initialization lists" or "assignment"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6)

Comment: Thank you all for your help, here is the solution I've used : 

         string _ipSMTP;
         int _port;

         Mail(const string& ipSMTP="localhost", int port = 25)
                    : _ipSMTP(ipSMTP), _port(port)
         {

Answer (score 1):

```
Mail(ipSMTP="serveurmail.com", port=25)
```

should be

```
Mail( std::string ipSMTP="serveurmail.com", int port=25)
```

You should also remove the `using` directive from header files:

```
using namespace std;
```

This is bad practice as it populates the global namespace with the contents of `std` wherever you include the header.

Answer (score 0):

You need to: (1) specify the types of the arguments; (2) initialize the relevant data members:

```
Mail(std::string ipSMTP="serveurmail.com", int port=25)
: ipSMTP(ipSMTP), port(port)
{
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters have type. As you probably want to initialize member variables you will want something like

```
Mail(const string& ipsmtp="serveurmail.com",int p=25) : ipSMTP(ipsmtp), port(p) {
    ...
}
```